# Class "Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Agent" not found

Tags: php, laravel

I get this error even when i have tried to reproduce            answers given to others
I have run  composer update,
composer update --no-scripts,
composer dump-autoload
but none worked.

I am new to laravel and i am trying to store input into my database

I dont know what to do anymore

My db table name is agents.
Agent.php (model)

```
    <?php
    
    namespace App\Models;
    
    use App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Agent as Authenticatable;
    use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
    use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;
    
    class Agent extends Authenticatable //line 12
    {
        use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;
    
    
          /**
         * The attributes that are mass assignable.
         *
         * @var array<int, string>
         */
        protected $guarded = [];
        // $fillable = [
        //     'name',
        //     'email',
        //     'password',
        // ];
    
        /**
         * The attributes that should be hidden for serialization.
         *
         * @var array<int, string>
         */
        protected $hidden = [
            'password',
            'remember_token',
        ];
    
        /**
         * The attributes that should be cast.
         *
         * @var array<string, string>
         */
        protected $casts = [
            'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
        ];
    
    
        public function property()
        {
            return $this->hasMany(Property::class);
        }
    
        public function agentbankdetail ()
        {
            return $this->hasOne(AgentBankDetail::class);
        }
    
        public function agentschedule ()
        {
            return $this->hasMany(AgentSchedule::class);
        }
    
        public function appointment ()
        {
            return $this->hasMany(Appointment::class);
        }
    }
```

RegisterUserController.php (controller)

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\Agent;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rules;

class RegisteredUserController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display the registration view.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\View\View
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('auth.register');
    }

    /**
     * Handle an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     *
     * @throws \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {



        $request->validate([
            'surname' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'othernames' =>['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:agents'],
            'password' => ['required', 'confirmed', Rules\Password::min(8)
            // Rules\Password::defaults()
            ->mixedCase()
            ->letters()
            ->numbers()
            ->symbols()
            ->uncompromised(),
        ],
            'whatsapp_phone' => ['required', 'digits:11'],
            'phone_number' => ['required', 'digits:11'],
            'referral_id' => 'sometimes|nullable|string', ['exists:agents,AgentId'],
        ]);



        $permitted_chars = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';

        function generate_string($input, $strength = 16) {
            $input_length = strlen($input);
            $random_string = '';
            for($i = 0; $i < $strength; $i++) {
                $random_character = $input[mt_rand(0, $input_length - 1)];
                $random_string .= $random_character;
            }

            return $random_string;
        }


        $idagent = generate_string($permitted_chars, 7);

        $idrefer ='3TQHOM3';

        $user = agent::create([
            'AgentId'=>$idagent,
            'surname' => $request->surname,
            'othernames' => $request->othernames,
            'email' => $request->email,
            'password' => Hash::make($request->password),
            'whatsapp_phone' => $request->whatsapp_phone,
            'phone_number' => $request->phone_number,
            'referral_id' => $request->referral_id ?? $idrefer,

        ]);

        event(new Registered($user));

        Auth::login($user);

        return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
    }
}
```

Comment: $user = agent::create([ ............... => $user = Agent::create([

Comment: @OMR I did that but it didnt work. It is still pointing at line 12 of Agent Model (Agent.php)

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using? There's no such thing as `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Agent` in 9.x. https://laravel.com/api/9.x/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth.html You're supposed to extend `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User`.

Comment: laravel framework 9.41

Comment: @ceejayoz I dont have User table. I have Agent table and Agent model so i though i have  to replace User with agent. Please, if possible, explain a little be more

Comment: @newdev Doesn't matter. Your agents still need to extend off `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User` if they need to be authenticable.